# Hide sticky section header background SwiftUI List

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a plain SwiftUI list with sticky headers.

I want to keep a clear background for the headers. Under iOS 15 it wasn't an issue but with iOS 16, a blurry background is added when the section header stays at the top. (see screenshot)

Is there some way to remove the blurry material ?

Minimal example of the issue:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Text("Some Cell")
                Text("Some Cell")
                Text("Some Cell")
                Text("Some Cell")

            } header: {
                Text("Some Header")
            }
            
            Section {
                Text("Some Cell")
                Text("Some Cell")
                Text("Some Cell")
                Text("Some Cell")

            } header: {
                Text("Some Header")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

[image: The list with a blurry section header]